# filesystemwatcher chrome cache in Visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to monitor all the folders in my pc except for the cache folder created by web browser such as chrome, firefox and IE. Basically those web browser create a new folder every time user click on it. So is there a way to ignore this folder since it's messing up the filesystem watcher.

This is basically the code that I tried out to monitor the changes

Dim watchfolder As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"))

```
    Dim attributes As FileAttribute

    attributes = File.GetAttributes(watchfolder)

    Dim fsw As New FileSystemWatcher(watchfolder)
    fsw.SynchronizingObject = Me
    fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = True
    fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes Or
                       NotifyFilters.CreationTime Or
                       NotifyFilters.FileName Or
                       NotifyFilters.DirectoryName Or
                       NotifyFilters.Size

    AddHandler fsw.Changed, AddressOf logchange
    AddHandler fsw.Deleted, AddressOf logchange
    AddHandler fsw.Created, AddressOf logchange
    AddHandler fsw.Renamed, AddressOf logrename

    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

I only have 1 partition so monitoring all file is easier. Just that when chrome is open, every click creates a temporary file and all the handlers basically triggered like always. Can I create a specific path not to monitor while monitoring the rest of the pc?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing how you initialize your filesystemwatcher.

Comment: Many, Many questions have already beena sked here...try search to see if similar questions have already been asked and answered...this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19408602/1070452

Comment: Thx for the guide. I'm very much new here.